# Find impedance matching in a quarter wave transformer

Tags: impedance-matching, smith-chart

I would like to know if there is a way you can find the impedance that has to be set between the load \$Z_L\$ **when it is complex** and the characteristic impedance \$Z_0\$ to have impedance matching without using the Smith Chart, since we are not allow to use it and all the methods I have search use it. It has to do something with the formula:$$Z_{in}=Z_1\frac{Z_L+jZ_1\tan\beta l}{Z_1+jZ_L\tan\beta l}=Z_0$$ and \$\beta l=(2\pi/\lambda)(\lambda/4)=\pi/2\$. The goal is to compute \$Z_1\$ and it seems always to be real.
The formula can be found in Microwave Engineering, Pozar, page 79, and with a scheme like this one:

[image]

also found in page 92, but the book specifies that \$R_L\$ is real.
The closest thing that I have found to my problem is this one:
[image]
but it uses the Smith Charts as it says so. In my problem \$Z_L=25-j175\$ and \$Z_0=36.11\$, giving a result of \$Z_1=\sqrt{75\cdot36.11}\$ but I don't know how that result has been achieved. Could it be related to a multiple media problem?

Comment: If you express the load in polar coordinates vs cartesian then find the conjugate length to match Zo then it is like using a Smith Chart

Comment: Martin - are we done here now? Do you need any further clarification?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear but I'll try to help

> Find impedance matching in a **`quarter wave transformer`**

For a quarter wave transformer \$Z_{IN} = \dfrac{Z_0^2}{Z_L}\$

> I would like to know if there is a way you can find the impedance that
>   has to be set between the load ZL when it is complex and the
>   characteristic impedance Z0 to have impedance matching

I interpret this as asking what impedance is placed between the end of the t-line and ZL to correctly terminate it? If so then the impedance has to be such that it cancels reactances i.e. 100 ohm inductive is cancelled by 100 ohm capacitive.

Answer (score 0):

When I remember right, Pozars formula should also be valid when ZL is complex. Just replace ZL real with ZL complex.